# Recursively Delete Files and Directories Using a Filter on the Directory Name

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory

I am attempting to delete all directories, sub-directories, and the files contained in them based on a filter that specifies the required directory/sub-directory name.

For example, if I have c:\Test\A\B.doc, c:\Test\B\A\C.doc, and c:\Test\B\A.doc and my filter specifies all directories named 'A', I would expect the remaining folders and files to be c:\Test, c:\Test\B and c:\Test\B\A.doc respectively.

I am trying to do this in PowerShell and am not familiar with it.

The following 2 examples will delete all of the files that match my specified filter, but the files that match the filter as well.

```
$source = "C:\Powershell_Test" #location of directory to search
$strings = @("A")
cd ($source);
Get-ChildItem -Include ($strings) -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force –Recurse
```

and

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\Powershell_Test -Filter A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
$source = 'C:\root\folder'
$names  = @('A')

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $names -contains $_.Name } |
  Sort-Object FullName -Descending |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

The `Where-Object` clause restricts the output from `Get-ChildItem` to just folders whose names are present in the array `$names`. Sorting the remaining items by their full name in descending order ensures that child folders get deleted before their parent. That way you avoid errors from attempting to delete a folder that had already been deleted by a prior recursive delete operation.

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can do all filtering directly with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem $source -Directory -Include $names -Recurse -Force |
  Sort-Object FullName -Descending |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: That looks very promising - I'll have to try that out and learn something new today. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it quite that simply.  This gets the list of directories, and breaks the path into its constituent parts, and verifies whether the filter matches one of those parts.   If so, it removes the whole path.

It adds a little caution to handle if it already deleted a directory because of nesting (the *test-path*) and the -Confirm helps ensure that if there's a bug here you have a chance to verify the behavior.

```
$source = "C:\Powershell_Test" #location of directory to search
$filter = "A"
Get-Childitem -Directory -Recurse $source | 
    Where-Object { $_.FullName.Split([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar).Contains($filter) } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName; if (Test-Path $_) { Remove-Item $_ -Recurse -Force -Confirm } }
```

Comment: Your filter was an array, but it wasn't clear from your question if you intended to have multiple items in that array.  If so, it's relatively straightforward to change the _Contains_ to something that iterates through the options in your array.